# Angular nested dropdown

Tags: html, angular, select, dropdown

I am attempting to create a dropdown list in Angular containing sub-items (as in the image but with all options selectable). Does anybody please know how to achieve this in Angular using the < select > tag so that I don't have to change other code within my application, as I would if changing to an unordered list etc.

Thanks :)

[dropdown list with sub-items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QtXA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the **groups of options** provided by [Angular/Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) library. See the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jamxonroyroj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-optgroup-example.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Use `class= "dropdown-submenu"`

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-toggle">Toggle</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      Sub List
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
        <li>Submenu Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or refer this https://mdbootstrap.com/support/general/how-to-create-a-nested-dropdown/

Answer (score 0):

Grouping sub-items can be achieved using angular material library.

For multi select drop down you just have to add `multiple` property in select tag element for selecting multiple options.

see the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sclwjw?file=src/app/select-optgroup-example.html) for reference.

For more such functionality using angular material, please refer [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)